# Can I save OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI) to a session variable in flask?

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth

Im building a flask app that connects to Google Search Console API.

I would like to save OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI) to a session variable so i can refer to it in a different flask route, where the user will submit the auth code and complete the authorisation process.

I have tried the following code:

```
...
            flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
            authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
            webbrowser.open(authorize_url,new=1,autoraise=True)        
            response_text = { "message":  fulfillment_text }
            Session['flow'] = flow
            return jsonify(response_text)
```

However, Im getting the following error:

Session['flow'] = flow
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Is there a way round this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The variable that you're storing in the [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.session) has to be serialized.

One way to serialize your object is to use `__dict__`.

```
session['flow'] = flow.__dict__
```

Comment: Thankyou Gabriel however i tried that but i still got the error message:

'Session['flow'] = flow.__dict__
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment'. Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Well, the error seems clear: the model object does not support item assignment. Are you importing the API packages correctly? https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python .Follow the sample.